# Getting absolute resource url with grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm actually working on sending a notification mail in my Grails application.

the problem which I'm facing is that i need to have the absolute path of an image resource  in order to have it appears in my mail

so in my mail template i used the following :

```
   ${resource(dir:"images" , file:"logo.png", absolute="true" ) }
```

but i'm always getting this instead of the full path to the resource

```
    static/images/logo.png
```

instead of

```
    http://localhost:8080/myApp/static/images/logo.png
```

how can i obtain the absolute url ?

Comment: Have you set 'grails.serverURL' property in Config.groovy? The value of 'serverURL' will be used to generate absolute URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: `absolute='true'` instead of `absolute: true`.

So, correct:

```
${g.resource(dir:"images" , file:"logo.png", absolute: true ) }
```

If you use it in template, also try `<g:resource dir="images" file="logo.png" absolute="true"/>`